# Javascript - Create Variable with If statement

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, html5-canvas

So. Im trying to create an "Alien Invasion" inspired game. And i was wondering how to correctly create a variable with an if statement.

Fx.

```
    if (gunIsShot){
     // Create variable 'theShot' 
    }

    var theShot{

     // theShot configs

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: `if (gunIsShot) { var theShot }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an if statement

```
var theShot;
if(gunisshot){
    theShot=1;
} else {
    theShot=0;
}
```

Or ternary operators

```
var theShot = gunisshot ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can i create mulitple instances of the variable this way? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "instances of the variable"?

Comment: You dont instanciate variables in js. If you know object oriented programming and try toapply the concept to your js app, you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work